# How to create separate folder for captured images with losing quality

Tags: android, android-camera

Hi i am trying to create **separate folder for captured images with out losing quality** using below code but i am getting exception **android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/myFolder/photo_20180504_102426.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()**

what did do mi-stack can some one correct my code

### code:

```
String folder_main = "myFolder";
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdirs();
            }
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/myFolder" + "/photo_" + timeStamp + ".png");
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

 private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

        try {

            Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            CircleImageView circleImageView = findViewById(formFields.get(imagePosition).getId());
            circleImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

Comment: Are you using FileProvider?

Comment: no i am not using

Comment: Then you took the wrong one from those thousand examples you found googling. Use a file provider!

Answer (score 1):

Put This on Your oncreate()

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

Comment: oh let me try and tell result

Comment: You can try. It works. But it is a bad shamefull solution. You should use a file provider.